# returning the lowest point in a list, consisting of multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_sink(m: List[List[int]], c: List[int]) -> bool:
    lowest_point = m[0][0]
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(len(m)):
            if m[i][j] < lowest_point:
                lowest_point = m[i][j]
    if c == lowest_point:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    """
    m = [[1,2,3],
         [2,3,3],
         [5,4,3]]
   >>> is_sink(m,[0,0])
        True
   >>> is_sink(m,[2,2])
        True
   >>> is_sink(m,[3,0])
        False
```

I'm trying to return True if c is the lowest in m. The code doesn't not print true or false

Comment: Be great if you can add a few sample `m` & `c` along with the result you'd expect for each.

Comment: I'm confused. Most of the code gives the impression that you are hunting for the lowest value in the matrix, and you are storing that value in `lowest_point` (which will be an `int`). On the other hand, `c` is a list, which means `c == lowest_point` will always be `False`. Maybe your intent is to find the lowest inner list in `m` and check whether it equals the `c` list? You can easily clarify by providing an example or two: inputs and expected results, as suggested by @chris.

Comment: an example is >>> m = [[1,2,3]

Comment: /n [2,3,3]/n[5,4,3]]

Comment: result : is_sink(m,[0,0]) would return true

Comment: also (m,[2,2]) would return true

Comment: @user10634542 You can edit your questions on StackOverflow: put the example inputs/outputs there so others can find it more easily. Also, provide both true and false examples.

Comment: i made some edits thanks

Comment: @user10634542 I'm still puzzling over your examples. (A) Why should `is_sink(m,[2,2])` return true? The lowest value in the matrix is 1, not 2, and `[2,2]` is greater than `[1,2,3]`. (B) Why should `is_sink(m,[3,0])` return true? (C) Is your intent that `c` always have 2 elements (like your examples); if so why? Maybe that will provide a clue....

Comment: yeah [2,2] the first 2 represent the third position in the main list while the second 2 represents the third position in the sublist. So what im trying to do if write a function what returns true if an elment is the lowest value in a sublist

Comment: ... but it (`[2, 2]`) is not the lowest. Why does your second example return True?

Comment: because the postion [2,2] is the smallest element in the sublist of the postion m[2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand the question: (a) the `c` list has 2 elements and is interpreted as indexes into the matrix `m`; and (b) return true if the value specified by those indexes is the lowest value within its sublist.

```
def is_sink(m, c):
    ci, cj = c
    for i, xs in enumerate(m):
        mn = min(xs)
        try:
            if i == ci and mn == xs[cj]:
                return True
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return False

MATRIX = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 3],
    [5, 4, 3],
]

print(is_sink(MATRIX, [0, 0]))  # True
print(is_sink(MATRIX, [2, 2]))  # True
print(is_sink(MATRIX, [3, 0]))  # False, because out of bounds
print(is_sink(MATRIX, [1, 0]))  # True
```

Comment: >>> (m , (0,1)) it returns true or false if its bigger or the smallest

Comment: youre right, i just have one observation, your result doesnt take into the fact that, the systerm is taking in lists for m and c

Comment: hey man, so i tried your code but it returns false in every instance

Comment: @user10634542 Well ... on my computer it behaves as shown above. Did you run my code as a stand-alone script or incorporate it into your larger program? If the latter, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I attempted to incorporate it into my larger program. Thank for your help. I will figure out the integrated aspect

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks for the lowest point, not whether that point is a sink. Also, I believe this is your homework, you should not be getting help for it online. Come to my office hours.